# Tool GUI automation using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to automate Metaware Debugger tool using Perl script. There are also command line options to run that tool. However, after invoking the tool and setting source and destination paths my script is losing control over the tool.

Is there any module or method by which I can achieve the entire tool control by Perl?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use the Expect perl module from CPAN, which was designed specifically to control command line applications.  This CPAN module is patterned after the famous Expect program that was written as an extension of Tcl to control command line apps.

[Click here for the latest version of Expect on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/)

[Click here for associated documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod)

Assuming you have working perl install and "cpan" command on your PATH, install the Expect package & dependencies using this shell command (in bash):

> $ cpan install Expect

**Update:**

Most people (including myself) won't have access to the proprietary Metware Debugger to test/demonstrate control of that specific tool.

Luckily, most command-line debuggers are fairly similar in terms of the way they interact with the terminal session, so hopefully a demonstration of controlling the `gdb` debugger with perl Expect module will translate fairly easily into your environment.

Here is an example perl script that uses the CPAN Expect module to control gdb debug session for a simple C program:

```
#!/bin/env perl

use Expect;

my @params = ("./x");
my $default_timeout = 3;

my $exp = new Expect;
$exp->raw_pty(1);
my $exp = Expect->spawn("gdb", @params)
  or die "Cannot spawn $command: $!\n";

$exp->slave->stty(qw(raw));

# Send commands to gdb session, wait for (gdb) prompt before each ->send
$exp->send("set args 4\n");
$exp->expect($default_timeout, [ qr/\(gdb\) /, sub { @_[0]->send("b main\n"); }]);
$exp->expect($default_timeout, [ qr/\(gdb\) /, sub { @_[0]->send("r\n"); }]);
$exp->expect($default_timeout, [ qr/\(gdb\) /, sub { @_[0]->send("n\n"); }]);
$exp->expect($default_timeout, [ qr/\(gdb\) /, sub { @_[0]->send("p a\n"); }]);
$exp->expect($default_timeout, [ qr/\(gdb\) /, sub { @_[0]->send("c\n"); }]);
$exp->expect($default_timeout, [ qr/\(gdb\) /, sub { @_[0]->send("quit\n"); }]);
$exp->expect($default_timeout, [ qr/\n/, sub { }]);
$exp->soft_close();
0;
```

Below is the C program file `x.c`, which you should compile using with `gcc -g -o x x.c` prior to running the perl script to control the gdb session.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 13;
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you will need to first use yum to install gcc and gdb if they aren't already on your system before you can compile the x.c file.

Comment: I am running it on Linux environment. Red-Hat Linux. I also thought about expect, but wasn't able to proceed.I also think i should try to play with the tool specific command line options. I am really thankful to you and any further help is appreciated !!!